# What is a good price for a taxi from Pristina airport to Mitrovica north station?

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, price, kosovo

I'm flying into Prishtina International Airport on Tuesday and want to know what a good price is for a taxi ride from there to North Mitrovica?

I'm thinking of negotiating for 25 or 30 euros. Is it possible to get that price? If it helps, I've learnt basic phrases and numbers in Albanian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They wanted €40, but I managed to get it for €35.

Answer (score 2):

Taxis from the airport to the city center [cost 10-20 euros](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g295385-i9418-k7082429-Transportation_from_pristina_airport_to_city_center-Pristina.html). Therefore a trip to Mitrovica (which is 2.5 times as far) should be around 40-50 euros, depending on your negotiation skills.